# Lightning bolt effect with particles is not continuous

Tags: xna, c#, xna-4.0, animation, monogame

I am Drawing a lightning effect animation using this image:

[image: im3]

Below the result:

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

As you can see the outcome is not a continuous purple color as I wanted it to be, but it has black spaces in between some parts.
The way i am drawing this animation is that i am drawing two `LightningBolts` every frame in Additive mode.
Every `LightningBolt` is drawn with the help of 21 random points across the width of the animation which makes `20 lines` of **various angles**.
So I rotate the texture I have to match each angle I calculated for each of those 20 lines for the two `LightningBolts` I am drawing in every frame in Additive mode.

What are your suggestions to overcome this problem ?

Comment: A quick idea would be to use the QUAD_STRIP primitive, [as seen here](http://3dgep.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/02/OpenGL-Primitives.png).

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens In the end what I did was to `skew` instead of `rotate`. But that's an interesting idea.

Comment: That was my point about the QUAD_STRIP, it does that automatically. But I'm glad you found a solution to your problem. Feel free to create an answer and accept it if you are done.

Comment: @AlexandreDesbiens Oh I thought you meant I would have to fill the gaps that way. The reason I didn't add this as an answer is because `skew` in XNA is really expensive (especially for a particle system like this one) and it needs to be done with a dynamic vertex buffer for performance which I haven't done yet.

Comment: See [this image](http://www.bur.st/~skinhat/skinhat/GLSceneDemos/wiki/meshmode/gl_quad_strip.jpg), you will understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not change the rotation. Change the y-position instead.

Another completely different approach which will look far better but might be far slower would be to draw the white core part of the lightning as a randomized path of line segments and then add the magenta halo in post-processing by taking the bolt, applying [gaussian blur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_blur), removing the green channel (to make in magenta) and draw the blur first and the original bolt second.

Answer (score 0):

Never done anything like that, but as an sugestion: what about the to draw the circle with gradient on each point between lighting parts? This will make the edges smooth, that might not be very much like a real lightning, but no ragged edges.

Comment: draw which circle ?

Comment: do you know if instead of rotating the texture, if i can draw it like this http://i.imgur.com/N2SId7I.png ? that would solve the problem

Comment: opened a question asking this: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/92499/drawing-image-with-an-angle/92500?noredirect=1#comment163617_92500

Comment: Sorry, can not add comment in second question. In the example, which have Peethor is precisely those same circles or rather halfcircles who need to draw on the joints. In the example, which have Peethor is precisely those same circles or rather polukruki who need to draw on the joints and they smooth them. On the result lighting they are looks like bright spots.